# Comedy Movies Description Write a query to list all the films existing in the 'Comedy' category and arrange them in the alphabetical order

Tags: sql

Sample Output

```
title

ACADEMY DINOSAUR
```

I tried the following code but it isn't producing the expected output such as that of the sample output. Someone please help me with this. Thank you

```
select Title
from film 
join film_category USING (film_id)
join category USING (category_id)
order by film_id = 'Comedy'
limit 1;
```

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a good problem description. I'm *guessing* you're getting a syntax error but, here's the thing, if you're seeing an error message, *we're not*. Please include the text of any error message, or if, say, it's producing incorrect results please tell us in what way they're incorrect.

Comment: Note that FALSE comes before TRUE. However, use WHERE to filter result instead.

Comment: Also, I'd rather expect `_category_ = 'Comedy'`

Comment: What fields are in each of your tables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your `inner join` are all fine.
But, as per the question:-

> list all the films existing in the 'Comedy' category

so, use `where` condition to filter only for `Comedy` category & you need not `limit 1`.
Also, the next part of the question:-

> arrange them in the alphabetical order

so, you need not use `ASC` after `where` condition.

```
select f.title
    from film as f
inner join film_category as fc
    using (film_id)
inner join category c
    using(category_id)
where c.category_id = '5'; -- or 'Comedy'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Title
from film
inner join film_category
using (film_id)
inner join category
using (category_id)
where name = 'Comedy'
order by title;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.